# hardware specification of Sony SmartEyeglass

Tags: sony-smarteyeglass

Can anyone out there provide further information on CPU, RAM, flash storage and battery type of the SmartEyeglass? I need this to compare the hardware specification with other smartglasses for my bachelor thesis. 
In addition, it would be nice to know if the firmware running on the SmartEyeglass is based on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Those hardware specifications are not publicly shared. SmartEyeglass is not Android based, but SmartEyeglass apps are Android apps that run on the smart phone.

SmartEyeglass acts as an accessory for the phone. SDK let's you display the user interface on the SmartEyeglass, take photos using camera of SmartEyeglass, get sensor data from SmartEyeglass.

To learn more about it, please consult to SDK pages.
https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/smarteyeglass-sdk/api-overview/

Comment: in addition, some hw info can be found here. E.g. battery type: http://developer.sonymobile.com/products/smarteyeglass/specifications/